# Images overflowing in CSS grid - how to fix?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I created a grid with two images columns and three rows and a gap between, but the images on the right are overflowing.

```html
<div class="main-container">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="./images/.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
```

```css
.main-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 1fr);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column-gap: 90rem;
    gap: 6rem;
}

.main-container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I tried adding both a min-height and min-width of 0px but it still overflowed, I was expecting it to stop the image from overflowing and to get rid of the scroll bars.

Answer (score 3):

Use `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);` or `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;`

`grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr, 1fr);` is incorrent. You will get **Invalid property value** error

To remove **horizontal scroll**, delete left and right margin in `.main-container img`

- If you need space between images, use `gap` property.
- If you need some space from the left or top, use padding of the parent container

This example below is how to get rid of **vertical** and **horizontal** scroll bar

```css
body {
    height: calc(100vh - 20px * 2);
    margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 90rem;
    gap: 6rem;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but my images still overflow.

Comment: I can see it now. Do you need margins in `.main-container img`?
Horizontal scroll disappears without them

Comment: that helped with the overflow, but for some reason there is still a vertical scroll bar.

Comment: is there any way to add space around an image without using margin?.

Comment: If you need space between images, use `gap` property. If you need some space from the left or top, use padding of the parent container

Comment: A vertical scroll bar isn't the problem, is it? What did you expect when your images are not fitted to the page?

Comment: Check the updated answer above. I included some CSS code example

Comment: I would like to get rid of it if i can, how can I fit my images to the page?.

Comment: Check if the example above works for you. In my case, all images resize to fit the container and horizontal scroll bar don't appear

Comment: It didn't seem to work.

Comment: Just to clarify, you copy paste code above and you still have a horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: no I don't have a horizontal scroll bar just a vertical one. The vertical scroll bar messes with my page layouts so I would Like to get rid of it.

Comment: Okey, I achieved this by calculating body height = 100vh (100% view height) - 2 * 20px (2 times top/bottom padding)

Comment: Check the example above :)